# OneToOne Field (with user) is returning numbers instead of usernames

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to extend default user model with a profile. I have a model called Profile that has a field called username which has one to one relationship with user.
I serialized this model to obtain a json response (which works) but username field gives integer output.
Normally I would call username.user, but how do I do it with json?
Is there a way to define output of a model field? I looked up in the documentation, but did not find anything relevant (maybe managers?).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using [natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm !